# Read user upload CSV file in RESTful

Tags: java, rest, csv

I try to save a user upload csv file in RESTful, the InputStream inputStream did carry some data at the resource level, but when it read the inputStream, no data can’t read!

```
@POST
@Path("/leveloverride")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)    
public Response handleSellerOverride(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream is, @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileInputDetails) throws IOException {
CSVReader csvReader = getCSVReader(is, fileInputDetails);
…
```

}

```
private CSVReader getCSVReader(InputStream inputStream, FormDataContentDisposition fdcDisposition) throws IOException{
    OutputStream outputStream = null;
    String qualifiedUploadFilePath = UPLOAD_FILE_SERVER + fdcDisposition.getFileName();

    try {
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(qualifiedUploadFilePath));
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        outputStream.flush();
    }
    catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        outputStream.close();
    }
    CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(qualifiedUploadFilePath));
    return csvReader;

}
```